# Does Dormant Sliver mean Slivers can no longer attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

- **[Dormant Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dormant%20Sliver)**

  - {2}{G}{U}
  - Creature -- Sliver
  - 2/2.
  - All Sliver creatures have defender.
  - All Slivers have "When this permanent enters the battlefield, draw a card."

It would seem if all Slivers have defender then they could no longer attack and would be like a wall. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This card, like Plague Sliver, falls into the category of "cards which may be effective *against* a Sliver deck, as well as in one".  Though it must be said that you don't want to cast Dormant Sliver, let your opponent's Sliver deck draw a ton of cards, and then glumly watch as the Dormant is removed when the moment to alpha strike is right...

Comment: Yeah, a better use is probably just in buildup-happy Sliver decks. "All your guys cantrip but you'll need a sacrifice outlet or some removal before you can alpha strike" is actually a pretty good deal.

Comment: Note that "like a wall" is incorrect. Except for earlier editions of the game, "Wall" is just a creature type, and has no special rules associated with it. A wall can attack unless it has the "defender" keyword. All older wall-type cards were given errata to have "defender."

Comment: @AlexP, of course, there are a number of slivers which grant a self-sacrifice ability, and one that gives a self-bounce ability, so that's not a particularly onerous requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes (you aren't missing anything).  With Dormant Sliver in play, no slivers will be able to attack.

As per the comp. rules:

> **702.3b** A creature with defender can't attack.